# appending elements of list to the next element of that list

Tags: r, loops, functional-programming, iterator

Imagine I'm working with a list of lists, as follows:

```
lol <- list(l1 = list(a = c(1:3), b = c(4:6), c = 2),
            l2 = list(a = c(1:3), b = c(4:6)),
            l3 = list(a = c(1:3), b = c(4:6)))
```

To which I want to apply a function, say:

```
foo <- function(x){
  sum(x$a, x$b)*x$c
}
```

The element `c` resulting from the first list needs to be appended to the next element in the list (`l2`) in order for the function to work. So the algorithm is:

A) Calculate `sum(a, b)` multiply by `c` -> results in `newc`.

B) Append `newc` to the next list, calling it `c`

C) Repeat

I know how to do this in a loop, as follows:

```
for(i in 1:length(lol)){
    s <- lol[[i]]
    s[["newc"]] <- foo(s)
    lol[[i]] <- list()
    lol[[i]] <- s
    if((i+1)<(length(lol)+1)){
      lol[[i+1]][["c"]] <- lol[[i]][["newc"]]
    }
}
```

For my case, I have to do this operation with a lot more data (more lists within the list) and iterated a lot of times (minimum 100) which gives me high runtimes (about 2s in some trials). As I need to use this with increasingly massive data, I would like to have alternatives to this loop.

EDIT: Thank you for your answers. I need to clarify though, that I need both c and newc in my lists. It wasn't clear before. Thank you.

Do you have any ideas on how to solve this without the loop?
Thanks!

Comment: Do you really need `newc` or to append `c` is enough?

Comment: @RuiBarradas to solve my problem, I need both.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem can be rephrased as to update the current element of the list based on the previous element of the list.
The loop can be simplified to a one-liner:

```r
lol <- list(l1 = list(a = c(1:3), b = c(4:6), c = 2),
            l2 = list(a = c(1:3), b = c(4:6)),
            l3 = list(a = c(1:3), b = c(4:6)))

foo <- function(x){
  sum(x$a, x$b)*x$c
}

for(i in seq_along(lol)[-1]){
  lol[[i]][["c"]] <- foo(lol[[i - 1L]])
} 

lol
#> $l1
#> $l1$a
#> [1] 1 2 3
#> 
#> $l1$b
#> [1] 4 5 6
#> 
#> $l1$c
#> [1] 2
#> 
#> 
#> $l2
#> $l2$a
#> [1] 1 2 3
#> 
#> $l2$b
#> [1] 4 5 6
#> 
#> $l2$c
#> [1] 42
#> 
#> 
#> $l3
#> $l3$a
#> [1] 1 2 3
#> 
#> $l3$b
#> [1] 4 5 6
#> 
#> $l3$c
#> [1] 882
```

<sup>Created on 2022-05-11 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

---

## Edit

Here is another solution, based on [Ritchie Sacramento's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72195082/appending-elements-of-list-to-the-next-element-of-that-list/72195386#comment127556028_72195082).

```r
lol <- list(l1 = list(a = c(1:3), b = c(4:6), c = 2),
            l2 = list(a = c(1:3), b = c(4:6)),
            l3 = list(a = c(1:3), b = c(4:6)))

foo <- function(x, y) {
  sum(y$a, y$b)*x
}

newc <- Reduce(foo, lol[-1], init = lol[[1]][["c"]], accumulate = TRUE)
Map(\(x, newc) {x[["c"]] <- newc; x}, lol, newc)
#> $l1
#> $l1$a
#> [1] 1 2 3
#> 
#> $l1$b
#> [1] 4 5 6
#> 
#> $l1$c
#> [1] 2
#> 
#> 
#> $l2
#> $l2$a
#> [1] 1 2 3
#> 
#> $l2$b
#> [1] 4 5 6
#> 
#> $l2$c
#> [1] 42
#> 
#> 
#> $l3
#> $l3$a
#> [1] 1 2 3
#> 
#> $l3$b
#> [1] 4 5 6
#> 
#> $l3$c
#> [1] 882
```

<sup>Created on 2022-05-11 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

---

## Edit 2

To also have `newc` in the result any of the following will do.
**Note** that like above the solutions have **different** functions `foo`. The second one is the function in Ritchie Sacramento's comment, now deleted, that I have reproduced above in the `Reduce/Map` solution.

### Solution 1, with `newc`

```
foo <- function(x){
  sum(x$a, x$b)*x$c
}

for(i in seq_along(lol)[-1L]){
  lol[[i]][["c"]] <- foo(lol[[i - 1L]])
  lol[[i]][["newc"]] <- foo(lol[[i]])
} 

lol
```

### Solution 2, with `newc`

```
foo <- function(x, y) {
  sum(y$a, y$b)*x
}

newc <- Reduce(foo, lol, init = lol[[1]][["c"]], accumulate = TRUE)
Map(\(x, c, newc) {
  x[["c"]] <- c
  x[["newc"]] <- newc
  x
}, lol, newc[-length(newc)], newc[-1])

lol
```

Comment: If I were to add the element newc to the list, I should just include it within the loop right?

Comment: @ZoetheSparkly Yes, I will edit the answer.

Comment: Besides, If I wanted to keep the same structure across all elements (a, b, c, newc), how will it modify the structure of the loop? I did the changes and worked but the last element does not contain newc because it is not implemented.

Comment: Edit2-solution1 works perfect and its approximately what I need to obtain the result intended. Solution 2 won't really work on my case as storing the results of the function in a different object is out of scope for now. I'm going to implement it to my case and hopefully it improves the running times. Thanks!

Comment: @ZoetheSparkly Yes, I also prefer the 1st solution, the 2nd needs two loops, `Reduce` and `Map`.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't use a loop:

```
lol <- lapply(lol, \(x) c(x, c=lol[[1]]$c))
lapply(lol, foo)
```

Comment: Is ```\(x)``` equal to ```function(x)``` in the context of the first lapply?

Comment: Yes. It's part of the language as of R4.1.